# Put a rounded parentheses in a label

Tags: labeling

I have this plot:

```
Plot[1 - 3 (x/l)^2 + 2 (x/l)^3 /. l -> 1, {x, 0, 1}, 
AxesLabel -> {x, Superscript[\[Psi] , (1)] [x]}, 
PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4], 
AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1.5], BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]
```

But the rounded parentheses are hidden (and I need them :-) )! Can I force mathematica to show them in some way?

Comment: Did you mean to use `"(1)"`...

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[1 - 3 (x/l)^2 + 2 (x/l)^3 /. l -> 1, {x, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, Superscript[\[Psi], "(1)"][x]}, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4], 
 AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1.5], BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]
```

[image]